# How to add existing view with own controller as a partial view to another view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, partial-views

i am using visual studio 2013 community edition.In my ASP.NET MVC application I had a view with model and controller as follows. I created the view from scafolding. It is database first approach. I added edmx file, then added controller with scafolding, which created views.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class request
{
    public request()
    {
        this.stocks = new HashSet<stock>();
        this.transactions = new HashSet<transaction>();
    }

    public int request_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> request_no { get; set; }
    public int request_status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<stock> stocks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<transaction> transactions { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MaterialManagement2.request

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>request</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.request_no, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.request_no, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.request_no, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.request_status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.request_status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.request_status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
namespace MaterialManagement2.Controllers
{
    public class requestsController : Controller
    {
        private MaterialManagement2Entities db = new MaterialManagement2Entities();

    // GET: requests
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.requests.ToList());
    }

    // GET: requests/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        request request = db.requests.Find(id);
        if (request == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // GET: requests/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: requests/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "request_id,request_no,request_status")] request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(request);
    }

    // GET: requests/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        request request = db.requests.Find(id);
        if (request == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // POST: requests/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "request_id,request_no,request_status")] request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // GET: requests/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        request request = db.requests.Find(id);
        if (request == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // POST: requests/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        request request = db.requests.Find(id);
        db.requests.Remove(request);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Now i need this view to be rendered as partial view with another view who has separate controller and model. I have created another view(partial) with above mentioned model with create template. This partial view called "_request" resides in shared folder. Now i used

`@Html.Partial("_request", new MaterialManagement2.request())`

in my another view so i can use them both is single view but the create button of the new view with partial view does not work. How do i make that button work?

Below is a screen shot of the app. The view renders correctly and looks exactly like i wanted. The button does not works though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the first controller name in this line :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "requestsController"))
```

and you should drop this in the submit button:

```
value="Create"
```